# Kendo grid Updating row are not in expected place after Update

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid with Inline Editable mode.When I am trying to Update a row , just after update it disappear or mixed up with all the entry's some where else.

Refreshing the grid or logging in again seems reappear this in the right place.

I want to have the Updated row (Inline Editable mode) at the same place where it was.

My grid is Below there

```js
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {

        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "GetTaskAllocationGrid",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
            },

            update: {
                url: "UpdateTaskAllocationData",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function (data) {

                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);

                    if (result.State == true)
                    {
                        toastr.success(result.Description);
                        //$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toastr.error(result.Description);
                    }
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "DestroyTaskAllocation",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function (data) {
                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);

                    if (result.State == true) {
                        toastr.success(result.Description);
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(result.Description);
                    }
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            create: {
                url: "CreateTaskAllocation",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function (data) {
                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);

                    if (result.State == true) {
                        toastr.success(result.Description);
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(result.Description);
                    }
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                if (operation != "read") {
                    return kendo.stringify(data.models);
                }

            }
        },

        serverPaging: false,
        pageSize: 10,
        batch: true,

        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "IDChargedTaskCatagory",
                fields: {
                    IDChargedTaskCatagory: { editable: false },
                    Task: { editable: true },
                    ChargeRate: { editable: true },
                    TaskReportingMetrices: { editable: true }
                }
            },
            errors: "Errors"
        },

        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.errors + "grid");
        }
    },
    editable:
        {
            mode: "inline",
            createAt: "bottom"
        },
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    toolbar: [
    {
        name: "create",
        text: "Add new record"
    }
    ],
    sortable: false,
    autoBind: false,
    create:function(e)
    {
        alert("create");
    },

    edit: function (e) {

    },
    update: function (e) {
    },
    columns:
    [
        { field: "IDChargedTaskCatagory", width: 50, hidden: true, title: "ID" },
        { field: "Task", width: 100, title: "Task Name" },
        { field: "ChargeRate", width: 100, title: "Charge Rate", editor: ChargeRateDropDownEditor },
        { field: "TaskReportingMetrices", width: 100, title: "Task Metric", editor: TaskMetricsDropDownEditor },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Action", width: "175px" }
    ]
});
```

anybody have any wise idea about this would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Would you please share the grid and it's datasource code?

Comment: I have added my grid code for better understanding